# determine the name of the sprite by position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have many SpriteNode:

```
sharesA.name = "sharesA"
sharesB.name = "sharesB"
sharesC.name = "sharesC"
ect.....
```

One of them has a position for example:

```
CGPoint(x: 1159, y: 406)
```

How to find out the name of the sprite being in this position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have the coordinate you could try:
`let name = nodeAtPoint(location).name ?? ""`

If you want to determine based on a user touching, you could try something like:

```
 class MyScene: SKScene {

     override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        var touch = touches as!  Set<UITouch>
        var location = touch.first!.locationInNode(self)
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
        let nodeName = node.name
     }
 }
```

Comment: nodeAtPoint returns the deepest visible descendant that intersects a point."background"

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear it! Please feel free to upvote and accept the answer. :)